# Algebra of upper triangular $n \times n $ matrices over field $ F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ideals

$\prod_{n \geq 2}  T_{n}(F)$  is product of   algebra of upper triangular $n \times n $ matrices over field $ F$.
I know that the ideal $I$  in $T_{n} (F)$ of matrices with $0$ on the diagonal is nil ideal. Then $\forall A \in I, A^{n} = 0$.$I$  is nilpotent  ideal, as well, but I have difficulty with $\prod_{n \geq 2}  T_{n}(F)$ .

> I don`t know how prove ideal $I_{n}$(matrices with $0$ on the diagonal )of the algebra    $\prod_{n \geq 2}  T_{n}(F)$       is nil?
>    Or even, why is $I=\bigoplus_{n} I_n\subset \prod_{n\ge 2}T_n(F) $ nil-potent?I have faced with difficulty to prove nil potency $I=\bigoplus_{n} I_n$

Comment: [Closed crosspost](https://mathoverflow.net/q/289672/19965)

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You denote by $I$ an ideal of $T_n(F)$, then by $I_n$ an ideal of $\prod_{n\geqslant2}T_n(F)$, then by $I$ again an ideal of $\prod_{n\geqslant2}T_n(F)$. Please use consistent notation. The ideal of $T_n(F)$ that you describe is nilpotent (hence also nil). The ideal of the product that you denote by $I_n$ is not nil (hence also not nilpotent); however since its description does not depend on $n$ I suspect you should have in mind a different ideal which is nilpotent. The ideal of the product that you denote by $I$ is nil but not nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

> I don`t know how prove ideal $I_{n}$(matrices with $0$ on the diagonal )of the algebra    $\prod_{n \geq 2}  T_{n}(F)$       is nil?

Nobody does, because this is false. If you pick an element of maximal nilpotency in each $T_n(F)$, then the element of the product will not have a finite nilpotency index.

> why is $I=\bigoplus_{n} I_n\subset \prod_{n\ge 2}T_n(F) $ nil-potent?

This $I$ is clearly *not* nilpotent since it contains elements of arbitrarily high nilpotency. BUT now you can show it is a nil ideal. For each element in $I$, there is a natural number $N$ such that the elements representation in $I$ is zero above the index $N$. Then the $N$'th power of the chosen element must be zero.

Comment: Is there an ideal in  $\prod_{n \geq 2}  T_{n}(F)$ so that it is nil and non-nilpotent?

Comment: @Jak Sounds like you need to read the solution above again.

Comment: Can you give further guidance on why this ideal can not be nil-potent?

Comment: @Jak It is obvious that there are elements with arbitrarily high nilpotence index. In a nilpotent ideal, the nilpotency indexes are bounded by some natural number.